# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make api using nodejs. Here i am making signup routes for api but the problem is every time i try to register user it says this.
Here is the whole error i am getting.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at C:/projects/blog-mern/backend/src/routes/users.js:7:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modu
les\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route
.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modu
les\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:28
1:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\expre
ss\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index
.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\r
outer\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modu
les\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\route
r\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:28
4:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\expre
ss\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index
.js:275:10)
    at C:\projects\blog-mern\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
```

This is my code

**models/users.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

schema.methods.setPassword = function setPassword(password) {
    this.passwordHash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10)
}

schema.methods.generateJWT = function generateJWT() {
    return jwt.sign({
        email: this.email,
    }, 'secret')
}

schema.methods.toAuthJSON = function toAuthJSON() {
    return {
        email: this.email,
        token: this.generateJWT()
    }
}

export default mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**routes/users.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/User';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body.users;
    const user = new User({ email });
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.save().then(userRecord => {
        res.json({user: userRecord.toAuthJSON()})
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})

export default router;
```

> i am sending request using postman
>   [image: parmas detail]

Comment: What line of code throws the error? Have you debugged the values?

Comment: have you mounted `body-parser`?

Comment: Where is the error? There are quite a few places where it could have come from, from multiple files.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar yes  i have mounted body parser. See i have updated my question.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález line 7 i guess where `const {email, password} = req.body.users` i guess

Comment: there should be more to the stack trace, can you paste few more lines, should be mentioned there *which* `email` it's refering

Comment: Line 7 in `models/users.js` or `routes/users.js`? EDIT: Ok, saw the edit.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález users.js

Comment: `req.body.users` is undefined, how are you sending from client? what is your `req.body.users`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar I am using postman to register email.

Comment: Can you add your postman request params/detail to the question? @naga-elixir-jar is correct.

Comment: also the headers, is it `application/json`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar yes it is `content-type: application/json`

Comment: and the body from postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you're trying to read `users` key from `req.body` which does not exist. Your origin req object does not contain `users`.

If you `console.log(req.body)`, the `req.body` will look exactly like your request:

```
{
  email: "adityakmr088@gmail.com"
  passwordHash: "12345"
}
```

Change your code to:

```
const { email, passwordHash } = req.body;
const user = new User({ email });
```

Comment: now This says `Error: data and salt arguments required
`

Comment: @adityakumar edit your question to include the stack trace (which you added earlier). Don't remove that, it's an essential part of the question